# How to inspect websocket traffic with charlesproxy for iOS simulator/devices

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, charles-proxy, cfnetwork

I would like to inspect network traffic going through **web sockets**, I have no control over the networking code as this is a binary lib for which I do not have the source code, so **I cannot do any log/breakpoint** in the networking part of the code.

I have tried using the latest version of **CharlesProxy** which claim to be able to sniff websockets however when I tried the url and apis using websockets were not even mentionned in the list of endpoints called from my iPhone.

[image: Version 3.11 release notes]

I have verified that CharlesProxy is configured correctly as I am able to inspect non-websocket traffic even under SSL.

So my question is: did anyone find a solution to inspect traffic going through websockets with CharlesProxy?

*Note: I have ATS disabled when using iOS9*

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have Charles 3.11.2 and still don't see websocket traffic.

Comment: I can't see websockets that come from ios in charles, however, I can see them when initiated from javascript

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this question?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons Yes it works fine with devices as well as simulators. In Charles go to Proxy Settings > Enable Socks Proxy. Enabling HTTP proxying over SOCKS might help as well.

Comment: We are using Starscream and WS data is not being picked up

Comment: I used what @matanwrites recommended and works great with latest Charles, Apollo iOS SDK Subscriptions which is based on top of Startscream. It was a hassle to deal with certificates and other buzz in SSL Settings though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

**Charles 3.11.2 works perfectly with WebSocket.**

I use [socketIO](http://socket.io/), so I've already seen http requests sent during the negotiation phase, but **I missed websockets traffic.**

In the beginning, socketIO try to use *polling* then switches to use *websockets*.

The websocket traffic is visible when you go to the request with status: *"Sending request body"* which is actually *wss://* request.

You even have a dedicated tab for this kind of traffic. The rest of messages will appear right there.

[image]

PS1. Ensure you're connected to socket properly then it appears in Charles.
PS2. I suggest using socketIO it's a great enhancement for full-duplex traffic like websockets.

Comment: Excellent! I was almost setting up Wireshark as an alternative.

Comment: The question was about web sockets with the iOS simulator.  There is no issue seeing web sockets with Charles when sending via JS.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE JUNE 2022:** Whilst socket.io-client-swift has an API to `enableSOCKSProxy`, it seems Starscream v4 has actually removed the built-in support for SOCKS proxying, so this option doesn't actually do anything!

[So it looks like we're back to manually patching Starscream to enable SOCKS proxying.](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/800#issuecomment-667583740)

Just to recap: we've gone from Starscream supporting SOCKS proxy but socket.io-client-swift not having an API to enable it, to now socket.io-client-swift having an API to enable SOCKS proxying, which Starscream no longer supports .

---

**UPDATE JUNE 2019:** Apparently socket.io-client-swift v15.1.0 now properly supports SOCKS proxy. I have not yet tried it, but it would mean that these manual edits to Starscream are no longer required.

---

The accepted answer does not seem to work with Socket.IO on iOS devices.

The latest version of Socket.IO-Client-Swift (15.0.0 at the time of writing) uses [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) for WebSockets on iOS/OS X.

The good news is that Starscream supports SOCKS proxying however:

1. Socket.IO does not expose the Starscream websocket or provide any API for enabling the SOCKS proxying behaviour.
2. The SOCKS proxying built into Starscream uses the OS SOCKS proxy settings which are cumbersome to setup (at least for iOS).

If I get some time I might propose a PR to address this more thoroughly, but given that it requires work to both Starscream and Socket.IO-Client-Swift, this is not entirely straightforward.

The easiest way to hack around this for temporary debugging purposes (which is the use case for Charles!), is to edit the `WebSocket.swift` file as part of Starscream, and replace this code:

```
if enableSOCKSProxy {
    let proxyDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()
    let socksConfig = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, proxyDict!.takeRetainedValue())
    let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy)
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, propertyKey, socksConfig)
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, propertyKey, socksConfig)
}
```

with this code:

```
let socksConfig = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()!.takeRetainedValue()) as! [String: Any]
let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy)
let ip = socksConfig["HTTPSProxy"]
let proxySocksConfig = ["SOCKSProxy": ip, "SOCKSPort": 8889, "SOCKSEnable": true] as CFDictionary // Where 8889 is the SOCKS proxy port in Charles
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, propertyKey, proxySocksConfig)
CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, propertyKey, proxySocksConfig)
```

This will ensure the SOCKS proxy is enabled by default, and will route all the websockets traffic via Charles.

You then need to ensure that the HTTP proxy settings are configured in iOS (since the same IP will be used for both HTTP and SOCKS), SOCKS proxy is enabled in Charles, and that the port matches the port in the code above (by default 8889).

Comment: It's still not working for me after updating WebSocket.swift. Would you be able to expand on the last section? I've enabled SOCKS proxy in Charles and the port matches but I wonder if I missed anything.

Comment: Never mind. I got it working. I missed that enableSOCKSProxy had to be true.

Comment: If you replace the entire section *including* `if enableSOCKSProxy { ... }` then you don't need to set `enableSOCKSProxy = true`, it will just be enabled by default for all connections....

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your very very helpful answer Jonathan Ellis! 
I'm using Pusher and this worked great!

However, I found `socksConfig` to not always contain valid data and didn't work or would crash the app when I pulled the IP from there.  Since the only thing we are getting from there is the localhost IP I just replaced the following in `WebSocket.swift`

```
if enableSOCKSProxy {
    let proxyDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()
    let socksConfig = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, proxyDict!.takeRetainedValue())
    let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy)
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, propertyKey, socksConfig)
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, propertyKey, socksConfig)
}
```

with this:

```
let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy)
let proxySocksConfig = ["SOCKSProxy": "127.0.0.1", "SOCKSPort": 8889, "SOCKSEnable": true] as CFDictionary // Where 8889 is the SOCKS proxy port in Charles
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(outputStream, propertyKey, proxySocksConfig)
CFReadStreamSetProperty(inputStream, propertyKey, proxySocksConfig)
```

And then enabled the socks proxy in Charles as you described.

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround solution:
After trying, I conclude that although iOS simulators follow system proxy settings for **HTTP**, **WebSocket** is not followed. Socks5 proxy settings is not followed, either.
However, we can use `Reverse Proxies` in Charles to force the simulator to use it.
In Charles, click `Proxy -> Reverse Proxies`, set up a local address to be your WebSocket server's transparent proxy, then use that address in your `new WebSocket(<address>)` (Well in the case of React Native), then you can see your WebSocket connections appear in Charles

Comment: Could you share an example with all fields please? Local address field is disabled by default

Answer (score 0):

**CharlesProxy with iOS WebSocket connection**

```
var rd: InputStream
var wr: OutputStream
```

```
let dict: NSDictionary = [
    StreamSOCKSProxyConfiguration.hostKey.rawValue : <ip>,
    StreamSOCKSProxyConfiguration.portKey.rawValue : <port>
]
rd.setProperty(dict, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socksProxyConfigurationKey)
wr.setProperty(dict, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socksProxyConfigurationKey)
```

or

```
let proxyDict = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings()
let prop = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(nil, 0, proxyDict!.takeRetainedValue())
rd.setProperty(prop, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy as String as String))
wr.setProperty(prop, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy as String as String))
```

CharlesProxy setup

```
Proxy -> Proxy Settings... -> Proxies -> Enable SOCKS Proxy
```

also you can check/review socket connection using [websocket-tester](https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester)

[image]

Please note that it should be used only in debug mode for security reasons and there is can be additional logic(e.g. checking signature...) which prevents intercept a traffic